# How do I invert key and value in RDD in Python 3 pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rdd

This works in Python 2.7, but in Python 3.5 it returns

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

I'm not sure if this has to do with the fact that "tuple unpacking" was removed from Python 3, as I read on another post, or is a different issue.

```
rddInverted = rdd.map(lambda (x,y): (y,x))
```

Comment: can you show what your data looks like?

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this:

```
rddInverted = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 5):

Your lambda function is on the row of the RDD, which is a tuple. Below is what you want.

```
rddInverted = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
rddInverted=rdd.map(lambda xy: (xy[1],xy[0]))
```